# Get % to work correctly for child elements of flex items

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Flex-items do not allow the % unit to work for their child elements unless the flex-item has a set height; however, often the reason to use flexbox is that setting the height explicitly would be difficult. Is there some sort of trick to make flex-items have their height and width be usable by CSS %?

Example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/0bpr07cz/

HTML:

```
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item">
        <div class="test-element"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.flex-container {
display: flex;
width: 400px;
height: 400px;
background-color: pink;
}
.flex-item {
flex-grow: 1;
background-color: yellow;
}
.test-element {
height: 100%;
background-color: green;
}
```

How would I make the flex-item containing the test-element have its height be usable by test-element's "height: 100%"? I need a solution that assumes the height of the flex-item is not known.

EDIT: I should have mentioned that the child of the flex-item is a widget made by someone else and thus changing the css on the child is not an optimal solution.

Comment: Why not just make the `.flex-item` another `display: flex` and then have `.test-element`s `flex-grow` too?

Comment: In the real code, the child element of the flex-item is a widget made by someone else; overwriting their CSS, while I have done it before, is tedious and error-prone.

Comment: Is the `.test-element` going to fill up the `flex-item` in both height and width?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0bpr07cz/1/)

You're trying to blend two styles here.  Why not continue "thinking in Flex" and just nest your flex items?

Your new **CSS**

```
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: pink;
}

.flex-item {
    flex-grow: 1;
    background-color: yellow;
    display: flex;
}

.test-element {
    background-color: green;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned in my question that the child of the flex-item is someone else's code and their relies on the height of that element being calculable by %.

Comment: Actually that did work since the height of the child of the flex-item isn't needed by the CSS % unit, but by JS (which accesses the clientHeight property, though I don't know why CSS % doesn't do the same).

Comment: Actually, the height just bypasses the element where it's not set and pulls it from the parent, where you've set it to `400px`.  That's why it works without the flex.